# how to remain login in fb sdk after rebooting the android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making facebook login page in android and on login i fetch user details but when i close app and restart it all my user details gone and login activity again start it,but fb ask for log out.My question is i want to remain login unlit i log out.my code is

```
      FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack=new 
FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


    // Facebook Email address
   GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject object,
                        GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.v("LoginActivity Response ", response.toString());

                  try {


                        Name = object.getString("name");
                      Email = object.getString("email");
                     // Gender=object.getString("gender");
                      BD=object.getString("link");




           profilePicUrl =   
     object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");

            //    tv1.setText(profilePicUrl);
          shared prefernce
                      SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(userLogin.this);
                      //now get Editor
                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                      //put your value
                      editor.putString("name1",Name);
                      editor.putString("mail2", Email);
                      editor.putString("picture", profilePicUrl);
                      //commits your edits
                      editor.commit();

                      Intent returnIntent = new 
    Intent(userLogin.this,tabLayout.class);
                      returnIntent.putExtra("name1",Name);
                      returnIntent.putExtra("mail2", Email);
                      returnIntent.putExtra("picture", profilePicUrl);

                      startActivity(returnIntent);




                      //    finish();

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });


    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

    parameters.putString("fields", 
   "id,name,link,email,picture.type(large)");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();




}

@Override
public void onCancel() {

}

@Override
public void onError(FacebookException error) {

}
};
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,mCallBack);

}
```

////

Answer (score 0):

check whether

```
if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null){// AccessToken is a class of fb sdk
     // try to login with facebook
     //show facebook login
}else{
  // get your data from Shared preferences
  // move to next activity
}
```

or

```
//check your sharedPreferences data first and if empty try to login
// else move to next activity
```

Answer (score 0):

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

```
                    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                                        try {


                                            //add your name/email/profile picture url parsing and sharedPreference code here


                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "" + "Unable to log In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }

                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture.type(large)");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    } else {
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                }
            }

    );
```

//code it like this way then it should work. Actually Facebook SDK keep your session in memory after you logged in , so it won't be logged out until you uninstall or remove your app from your account.Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Man... It's working Great ... You saved my time :)